# Regex New RegExp - Replace all text instead of [game_name]

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic

I need some help and hope someone can help me with this issue:

```
hturl = "\[game_name\]"
var myregexp = new RegExp(hturl, "ig"); 
contentreplace = contentreplace.replace(myregexp, '\[game_namexxxx\]');
```

The above regex replace all the text like this

> [game_namexxxx]ll you h[game_namexxxx]v[game_namexxxx] to bri[game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx] [game_namexxxx]lo[game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx] th[game_namexxxx] [game_namexxxx]o[game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx]t you pl[game_namexxxx]y [[game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx][game_namexxxx

instead of replacing only [game_name] with [game_namexxxx]

Thanks

Comment: Please post the original text as well, it's impossible to find your regex error if you just show the "broken" result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\\[` instead of `\[`.

`\[` in a string literal escapes `[`, so the string literal will actually yield the string `[`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Gabi - I have tried to use \\ and it did not work - Then you mentioned the samething and I tried it again... and now it WORKS :-) Thank you very much - it is appreciated!

Comment: +1 For seeing the escaping problem. I didn't. ;) @Gerald: If the regex is really built from a string variable (as the comment under my answer suggests), this variable should be regex-escaped first or the regex will break again at some point: `var hturl = hturl.replace(/[-\\[\\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|]/g, "\\$&");`

Comment: Hi Tomalak thanks for the tips - The variable is always a game name, with no spesial characters. (but I am also translating it into various languages, and this is where your suggestion is going to come in handy - Thanks!